# How can I open the currently running script's .py file using IDLE in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

In a GUI app written in Python and Tkinter, I want to add a menu command which will open the source code of the *.py file in IDLE. I also want it to be platform independent.

I've tried using `os.system` to open IDLE from Scripts folder of Python, but that would be platform dependent. I couldn't find a way to get the Scripts folder of Python to make it independent. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a file in an IDLE editor, the command line is

```
<python> -m idlelib <path>
```

where `<python>` is the full path to a python executable or a name that resolves to such.  If you want to open IDLE with the same python that is running you python app, which is likely what you want, use the platform-independent `sys.executable`.  The path to the source code for the running app is `__file__`.  This is one of the semi-hidden global variables when python runs a file.  Or give the path to any other file.

Whether you use `os.system` or `subprocess` is a different issue.  The latter is more flexible.  `subprocess.run` replaces `os.system`.  `subprocess.Popen` should not block.  IDLE uses the latter to run user code.

Comment: I don't know much about executables in Linux, OSX or MacOS; will `subprocess.Popen(f"{sys.executable} -m idlelib {os.path.realpath(__file__)}")` work in all operating systems?

Comment: I believe so, or the list form `Popen([sys.executable, '-m', 'idlelib', __file__])` should.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some special way:

```
    import idlelib.pyshell
    import sys
    sys.argv.clear()
    sys.argv.append("")
    sys.argv.append(fName)
    idlelib.pyshell.main()
```

It works! But I don't know whether this way will generate some problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).